# SQL replace array field with corresponding values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL tables, similar to the ones below:

table_a:

```
ID | Scenarios
1    1;2;3;4;
2    3;4
```

table_scenarios:

```
ID | Unit
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
```

What I want to do is to make a single SQL statement that should replace the values from table_a field Scenarios with the corresponding values from table_scenarios
The output should look like:

```
ID | Scenarios
1    A;B;C;D;
2    C;D;
```

How could I achieve that without using VBA coding?

Comment: I know I'm stating the obvious, but just in case it isn't... you will save yourself a lot of pain and grief going forward if you take the time to normalize your data instead of concatenating values in a column like that.

Comment: Ugh. Your table is in serious need of normalization. What you have here violates 1NF and the reason you are struggling with this. What you will have to do is first parse the denormalized values into rows, that will allow you to join to your lookup table. Then you will have to squash these values back into a single tuple again. This is not the right way to handle data.

Comment: You should re-factor your tables.  Having a string of many delimited values in a single field is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  You 'should' normalise your structure to have each `ID:Scenario` relationship in its own row.  So, for example, you'd have `{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}` as ***six*** rows rather than as two rows.

Comment: This is a known problem and is currently [#1 on the list of top 10 problems with SQL](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/05/24/5248.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** As the comments rightly point out, this is far from an optimised way of structuring your data. Strictly you should restructure your table, but if you are constrained to do it this way, then the following works.

Using a string split table valued function (copied from [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/))

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

You can achieve the results you are after using the following query:

```
;
WITH    CTE_Units
          AS (
              SELECT    ta.ID,
                        ts.Unit
              FROM      #table_a AS ta
              CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(ta.Scenarios, ';') split
              INNER JOIN #table_scenarios AS ts ON split.splitdata = ts.ID
             )
    SELECT  units.ID,
            STUFF((
                   SELECT   ';' + CTE_Units.Unit
                   FROM     CTE_Units
                   WHERE    CTE_Units.ID = units.ID
                  FOR
                   XML PATH('')
                  ), 1, 1, '') + ';' AS Scenarios
    FROM    CTE_Units units
    GROUP BY units.ID;
```

Result:

[image: Result output]

Comment: If you are going to use a splitter from SSC you should really not use that one. A loop is just a horribly inefficient way of splitting strings. Here is a MUCH better alternative from there. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Here is another link to other great splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1):

With the help of XML and CTE:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml = (
SELECT CAST('<i id="'+CAST(ID as nvarchar(max)) + '"><s>' + REPLACE(Scenarios,';','</s><s>') + '</s></i>' as xml)
FROM table_a
FOR XML PATH(''))

;WITH final AS (
SELECT  t.v.value('../@id','int') as Id,
        ts.Unit
FROM @xml.nodes('/i/s') as t(v)
INNER JOIN table_scenarios ts 
    ON ts.ID = t.v.value('.','nvarchar(10)')
)

SELECT DISTINCT id,
        (SELECT Unit +';'
        FROM final f1
        WHERE f.Id = f1.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) as Scenarios
FROM final f
```

Output:

```
id  Scenarios
1   A;B;C;D;
2   C;D;
```